# KDE asking for password to mount external hd

Tags: mount, kde, gui, external-hdd

Any ideas as to why kde asks for root password when mounting an external hd (using the gui)? It did not use to do that. Has something changed in the way thing used to work?

Comment: These permissions aren't really handled by KDE, they are handled by polkit.